# Why jHipster use oracle 12c configuration? Is there any issue if using oracle 11g configuration?

Tags: java, maven, oracle11g, jhipster, oracle12c

I'm using jHipster 4.7.0.

As there is the only option for Oracle 12c code generation I've updated the JDBC dependency and registry for Oracle 11g and it is working fine but what I want to know is that why there is not a configuration option for Oracle 11g. Is there any problem that I might face in future, if so, Kindly tell me.
These are the update entries in my pom file.

```
<repository>
<!-- Repository for ORACLE ojdbc6-->
<id>codelds</id>
<url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And Update dialect to 10g in dev and prod profile.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why Oracle 12c is the only supported version, is that the project team does not have the bandwidth to test all versions:

- We do the same thing for all other databases, and most of them are Open Source (so a lot easier to test!)
- Oracle 11 is already EOL by Oracle - only people with "extended support" can use it until 2020. So we're not going to support something that the editor itself doesn't support.
- There is no Mac OS X support for Oracle (and most of the team uses Mac OS X)
- Oracle does not sponsor us at all, so we have no license for the project: we can only use the "express" edition, which is limited

Concerning the last two points, one solution is the Oracle Docker image on Docker Hub, but it's very annoying to use (very big), it has some limitations, and I'm not totally sure this is legal to use.

So there's nothing against Oracle 11, but we might use some Oracle 12-specific features - typically I'm waiting to be able to use table names and FKs with more than 30 characters - so the more you wait to upgrade, the more risk you have.